# Single Use Token without a database

Tags: design

Is there a way to generate a single use token for password recovery, without using a database?

This is because, I have an application that doesn't have a database, and doesn't store or has access to the login database. I use a Web Service to login the users, and store everything I need on a session. So there is no need for a database.

I can create a token, that will be available for a certain amount of time, but that doesn't mean it will not be used more than once.

## Edit:

There is a database, which has all the data of users.  The application doesn't access it, but through a Web Service.
To this Web Service the application sends the credentials, and the Web Service replies if it's valid or not.
When you successfully log, it will show you information regarding your user, which means, the application will use a series of Web Services to gather this information.
All these Web Services are only available to the local network.

The optimal solution would be to modify the Login Web Service. But since it's so old, they don't want to modify it, but completely change it, eventually.

Right now, we need to add a way for users to recover their password. And we need a quick solution, not redo the Login Web Service right now, nor modify it.

## Possible solution:

I can generate a token, no problem with that, and then send it to the user.
This token will be the encrypted date before the token expires, along with some data to make it unique to the user.
This token will be read and if it's expired, it will be ignored.

Ideally, as soon this token is used to successfully change the user's password, it would update the database to let it know the token was used. But since this doesn't exist, nor we can have it right now, there is no way to know when the token was used.

We are thinking of maybe storing the temporary tokens on cache. I could ask opinions on that approach, but that would probably be off topic.

Thanks for all your enquiries and ideas.

Comment: Are you able to retrieve any information from your login provider such as timestamp for last password change?

Comment: No, and if it exist I don’t access to it. Thanks though that is pretty good idea.

Comment: Is your problem uniqueness?  Create a GUID.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem, as I understand it is preventing reuse.

Comment: By someone else?  They would have to guess the GUID.  Expire it once it is used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm guessing this is related to [concerns about 2FA using SMS](https://usa.kaspersky.com/blog/2fa-practical-guide/16398/).  How do you expire a number?

Comment: If you're going to get into two-factor authentication, you probably need a "real" system, and not one that depends on ephemeral sessions.

Comment: So essentially a session token? What do you mean "password recovery" If you have no password database how can you "recover it?"

Comment: How do you change the password on the web service you connect to? It must require some sort of token itself, doesn't it? Can't you use that same token?

Comment: `I have an application that doesn't have a database, and doesn't store or has access to the login database` Then why do you need to add a password recovery feature, if you are not in control of the password database?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. We decided that we will just use a temporary token that will be available for 24 hours, and that's the end of it. They will be able to change the password for the duration of the token, but there's nothing else we can do with this restrictions. Thanks agains.

Comment: Ok, you don't have a database. Then please tell us where are the passwords stored. Can't you use the same data store to persist tokens which have to survive a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bad practise but you can store a value on app cache to make the token verification (iisue date, duration,user id).
This could be a way (depending on the amount of users) and you have to delete expired tokens once a while.